# Vuejs for creating dynamic survey forms with yes/no nested questions

Tags: vuejs2

I have to design a forms which i have show a questions with the nested multiple questions. First questions will always be Radio button with yes/no options.

The nested questions could also be yes/no or input box or dropdown.

I wanted to create the survey forms dynamically with `bootstrap`, `vue js` and `Kendo-ui` for date picker.

For the validation i will pass the required properties in the input.

Basically my questions setup look like this.

[image: What i wanted to do]

So, far what i have implemented.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {},
  data: {
    tabIndex: 0,
    Q: [{
        id: 1,
        value: null,
        question: "Are you at least age 16?",
        type: "radio",
        options: [{
          text: "Yes",
          value: "0"
        }, {
          text: "No",
          value: "1"
        }]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: null,
        question: "Are you a college Graduate?",
        type: "radio",
        name: "college",
        children: [{
          id: 3,
          value: null,
          question: "Please Select Your degree.",
          type: "text",
          name: "degree",
          options: null
        }],
        options: [{
            text: "Yes",
            value: "0"
          },
          {
            text: "No",
            value: "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-row class="justify-content-center">
    <b-col md="8">
      <b-card no-body>
        <b-tabs warning pills card vertical v-model="tabIndex" nav-wrapper-class="collapse-navbar">
          <b-tab title="Education Information" title-item-class="disabledTab">
            <div v-for="(q, name) of Q">
              <b-card>
                <template v-if="q.type == 'radio'">
                  <b-form-group :label="`${++name}. ${q.question}`">
                    <b-form-radio-group v-model="q.value" :options="q.options" name="radioInline">
                    </b-form-radio-group>
                  </b-form-group>
                </template>
              </b-card>
            </div>
          </b-tab>
        </b-tabs>
      </b-card>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</div>
```

Basically i am struck in the implementation two different logic

**One**

Logic for implementation of scenario for question number 2 (in the image above). How should i toggle the div with the input box and date picker like shown in the image above. How should i create my input **Q** `Array` and model the `v-for`?

**Two**

I am struggling to bind the value from all the radio buttons on a array. or in list.
...

Answer (score 0):

For your issue #1:

To start with the data is insufficient as the questions doesn't seem to have the optional questions that you will be asking based on the radio buttons.

Here is an plain HTML implementation with optional questions. You can adapt it for bootstrap-vue accordingly.

https://jsfiddle.net/tecoholic/hL68h2v2/

Short answer is, store a value called `condition` in the optional question with the expected value when the optional questions should be displayed and do `v-if="q.value === condition` on the questions.

Comment: I have updated my questions for issue #1 on the code.